# How do I submit my site for proper SEO under my setup which is complicated?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, ssl, seo, google-search

I have:

1. www.example.com (Wordpress)
2. www.example.com/blog (wordpress)
3. www.example2.com(prestashop) (Existing 301 http://example2.com-->https://www.example2.com)
4. www.example2.com/blog(wordpess)

I have multi-domain ssl for www.example2.com (primary CN) and SAN(www.example.com) using SNI. **The non-www versions are not covered.**.
Example2.com is primary domain in cpanel while example.com is the add-on.

I want www.example.com and www.example2.com to be under full site SSL. But for the 2 blogs I wanted SSL for only donation pages.

**Question 1**
If I use 301 redirect from https://example.com-->https://www.example.com will it solve browser error issue?(Both sites) Will this move of not covering the non-www versions under SSL impact google crawl negatively and penalize me?

**Question 2:**
 Since I use wordpress, I found that non-www version leads to www version without me editing .htaccess. (I just setup www in admin panel) Does wordpress use 301 internally and does it satisfy the need for google too to pass on link juice/avoid duplicate content?

**Question 3:** 
Does the future seem to be full site SSL? If so,in how many years do you think is the outlook?

**My SEO questions are:**

**Question 1.**

In search console, can I specify the non-https version for the blog
 (http://www.example.com/blog) as preferred while https version as preferred for www.example.com (https://www.example.com)?

**Question 2.**

How do I submit the site? Do I declare each domain (example.com) and
    subdirectory (example.com/blog) as a property(www+non-www) and then
    declare each with and without https?

**2a.** Does google consider example.com and example.com/blog as 2 separate sites or the same ( Content vastly different)? How do I use the blog to increase www.example.com ranking in such a case? My key point being one is full https and the other is not.

My preferred domain is https+www. For both my main sites (not blogs).

**2b.** How does google see the website (Does it consider it as full https) if the main domain is https while the sub-directory is not full SSL?

Will google consider example.com full HTTPS if I redirect 301 to https+www for example.com and http(without S) +www for the blog.  I want rank benefit of SSL in the future as I think google will increase in 5 years the raking factor for SSL.

**Question3.**

If I use adsense, will it place non-https ads on the blog as it is
    not https even thou main site is https+www as preferred? (I can’t
    understand how will google look at example.com and example.com/blog
    –separate or different sites for adsense+SEO specially when ssl is involved!! )

**Question 4.**

I read link juice flows from subdirectory to main domain. But my
    main domain is full https (Wordpress 1) and subdirectory is not
    (Wordpress 2). Do I get SEO benefits in such a case?

**Question5.**

What happens to SEO link power when people link back without the
https? Will the redirect help to save the juice? (100% or partially)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better asked on the sister site: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com rather than here as not related to programming but here goes anyway:

> Question 1 If I use 301 redirect from
>   https://example.com-->https://www.example.com will it solve browser
>   error issue?(Both sites) Will this move of not covering the non-www
>   versions under SSL impact google crawl negatively and penalize me?

If your cert does not cover non-www version then you will not be able to set up this redirect as will not be able to connect to https://example.com successfully to get that redirect message (you cannot send redirect before you make this secure connection).

For best SEO you should pick one version and redirect everything to it (e.g. redirect https://example.com and http://example.com and http://www.example.com all to https://www.example.com).

> Question 2.
>
> How do I submit the site? Do I declare each domain (example.com) and
>   subdirectory (example.com/blog) as a property(www+non-www) and then
>   declare each with and without https?

Each protocol and domain is a separate site to Google. So you should have four for each https domain (https://example.com, http://example.com, http://www.example.com and https://www.example.com) and ahoukd register them all but redirect everything to your primary domain as above.

You should have one sitemap for your primary domain unless, for some reason you need to have two (e.g. Not all pages can be served over https) in which case you should have two site maps with each URL in the appropriate one.

Example.com/blog is not a separate domain. It's just pages on the example.com domain.  I don't see why you wouldn't have your blog on https though since you obviously have a cert for example.com. HTTPS is going to increasingly become the norm and Google is already treating it as a (very small) ranking signal.

> Question3.
>
> If I use adsense, will it place non-https ads on the blog as it is not
>   https even thou main site is https+www as preferred?

Yes it can. Though again why complicate matters. Why not go HTTPS for your blog.

> Question 4.
>
> I read link juice flows from subdirectory to main domain. But my main
>   domain is full https (Wordpress 1) and subdirectory is not (Wordpress
>   2). Do I get SEO benefits in such a case?

Yes, but not as much as if on same site, as Google will see them as separate sites.

> Question5.
>
> What happens to SEO link power when people link back without the
>   https? Will the redirect help to save the juice? (100% or partially)

Yes it will help but yes you will get a small hit for going through a redirect. Not much you can do about it.

Comment: You saved my life before launch. Thanks a ton! However I had to clarify your answer for question 2. You suggested that I do not need to register my blogs as separate properties but I was confused by google's suggestion found [link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en). It says "Enter the URL of exactly the domain, subdomain, or path branch for which you want to get data. Here are some examples of URLs that you might add: http://www.example.com/foo/ - Records data only for the subpath /foo/ of www.example.com.

Comment: Also found under previous link, we recommend creating a separate Search Console property for each domain or folder that you want to track separately, Could you pls advise :)

Comment: If you want to track it separately then you can. But you don't have to as it will also be tracked under the main domain without path - which you should always register at least even if you want to also register the blog one separately.